# Laravel distinct result

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I'm building a PM system, and I have a problem.

This is my PM table:

```
id, user_id, to, content
```

Now, in my inbox page I'm fetching all the users that sent me a message.

```
$pms = DB::table('pm')->select('user_id')->distinct()->where('to', Auth::id())->get();
```

The problem is if I add more columns to the select method, it won`t be distinct anymore..

Comment: What are you expecting to. Do you want all messages or only distinct user_id ? If you group by user_id you won't have all messages

Comment: Why do you need more columns?

Comment: why u are not using eloquent?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that using Eloquent and its **whereHas()** method.

First, define models and the relation in your model:

```
class Message extends Model {
  protected $table = 'pm';
}

class User extends Model {
  public function sent_messages() {
    return $this->hasMany(Message::class);
  }
}
```

Now, fetch all users that have a related **Message** models where **to** column matches your ID:

```
$usersThatSentMeMessages = User::whereHas('sent_messages', function($query) {
    $query->where('to', Auth::id());
});
```